# Difficulty with node-mssql event listeners

Tags: node-mssql

My node app is crashing when node-mssql executes a stored procedure with a TVP parameter that violates its type's primary key constraint.

```
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The data for 
the table-valued parameter 1 doesn't conform to the table type of the 
parameter. SQL Server error is: 3602, state: 30
```

I've tried handling the error in a number of ways including adding event listeners. I suspect I'm using them incorrectly but haven't managed to figure out exactly how.

```
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

sql.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
})

const tvp = new sql.Table('EventsMultiplicativeType');

tvp.columns.add('MUID', sql.Int);
tvp.columns.add('DateID_Start', sql.Int);
tvp.columns.add('Value', sql.Float);
tvp.columns.add('Number_Consecutive_Observation', sql.Int);
tvp.columns.add('Detail', sql.VarChar(sql.MAX));
tvp.rows.add(8750, 20180101, 5, 5, 'Hello');
tvp.rows.add(8750, 20180101, 5, 5, 'Hello');

sql.connect(dbConfig).then(pool => {
    pool.on('error', err=> console.log(err));
    return pool.request()
        .on('error', err => console.log(err))
        .input('EventTable', tvp)
        .execute('sp_ValidateEventsMultiplicative')
        .then(result =>console.log(results))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}).catch(err => console.log(err));

sql.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```